# "CLR_E_ENTRY_NOT_FOUND" error while compiling the project

Tags: .net, .net-micro-framework

I am using NETMF 4.1 and I have this error with the source, which can be found at

http://www.skewworks.com/ftpserver/

I am trying to deploy an FTP server on a FEZ COBRA II (https://www.ghielectronics.com/docs/48/fez-cobra-ii-developer)

The error is ** **CLR_E_ENTRY_NOT_FOUND ** ....in MMP file.**

How do I resolve this for the application to run.

Comment: I am using VS2012 and NETMF 4.1

Comment: I searched few forums in whihc one of them says that I have to check up the assembly reference but it was not specific....

Comment: That's not a valid CLR error code.  Is it CLR_E_ENTRYPOINTNOTFOUND?  It is pretty doubtful you'll find an SO user to dig through a bunch of code, use the vendor's support channels to find help.  They promise "world class support", clearly you'll want to take advantage of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this error.....Well the error was because I was using outdated namespaces from GHI electronics (v 4.1) which was NETMF namespace, it must be replaced by using the GHI.Premium (v 4.2)package then there you are all set, except few other like networking clasees must be chaged. if any one comes across this one ....I hope this helps you people.